# React Native - Debugging Errors

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I've just started to learn React-(Native) and I'm not feeling comfortable to debug errors. Mostly all of them doesn't point to any line from my code and this makes really hard to find solutions.

For example:
[image: Error Case]

In this case, how could I find from what of my lines this exception was called?

Also, if you know how to solve this problem heres the code:

## index.js

```
import {
    StackNavigator,
  } from 'react-navigation';

import LoginScreen from './loginView'
import HomeScreen from './homeView'

export default screens = StackNavigator({
    Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
    Login: { screen: LoginScreen },
  });
```

## loginView

```
import {StackNavigator,} from 'react-navigation';

import LoginScreen from './loginView'
import HomeScreen from './homeView'

export default screens = StackNavigator({Home: { screen: HomeScreen },Login: { screen: LoginScreen },});
```

## homeView

(paste not working)
https://pastebin.com/YsnVkinQ

## index.android.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import screens from './app/index';

import {AppRegistry,StyleSheet,Text,View} from 'react-native';

AppRegistry.registerComponent('estudo1', () => screens);
```